# Bintray response conflict with error code 409

Tags: android-studio, gradle, bintray

We've an Android Studio project on which we collaborate together.
A colleague has setup a bintray.com to gather there all required libraries within our android Studio project. We both have our accounts there, we've setup our bintray API key and corresponding github username in the `gradle.properties` file. For him it works fine and he gets the uploaded libraries like `test-1.0.0.pom`; but I don't.

Instead I get

> Error:Could not GET 'https://oss.jfrog.org/artifactory/oss-snapshot-local/xxx/yyy/zzz/1.0.0/test-1.0.0.pom'. Received status code 409 from server: Conflict
>   Enable Gradle 'offline mode' and sync project
>
> Gradle sync failed: Could not GET 'https://oss. ... with very same error message

**So I am conflicting with the server ? What am I doing wrong?**

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to upload the same library (`test-1.0.0.pom`) that your colleague has uploaded, the 409 is expected and right. You can't override a release version of a library.

Generally, you are using a wrong tool. Bintray is a distribution platform, that is intended to distribute libraries that are released to the outside world.
What you are looking for is a something like [artifactory](/questions/tagged/artifactory) – a tool to collaborate during development. Go ahead and install a free [Artifactory Open Source](http://jfrog.com/open-source/), it works great with Gradle.

<sup>I am with [JFrog](http://jfrog.com), the company behind [bintray](/questions/tagged/bintray) and [artifactory](/questions/tagged/artifactory), see [my profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/402053/jbaruch) for details and links.</sup>